# Condition in FOR loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm making a simple lottery simulator. I have two mutually exclusive command line flags, so either the program performs amount of draws the user specifies or until you hit the Jackpot.

```
for i in range(args.draws):
    perform lottery draws here
```

How to modify the for loop in a way that if args.draws is not given it should
run until jackpot is hit. I am now defaulting the args.draws to a very high number
so in almost all the cases the Jackpot is hit and then break the loop, but is there
better way to do this

Here is the whole code. It is not pretty Im just learning Python

```
import random
import argparse
def oneoutof(occurance, times):
    if occurance == 0:return 0
    return float(times)/float(occurance)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LOTTERY_NUMBERS = [i + 1 for i in range(39)]
    WIN_LIST =[0,0,0,0]
    six_plus_one = 0
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="[Lottery]\n"
    "Example: python3 lottery.py ")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

    group.add_argument("-s","--seven",action="store_true",
        help="Stop when you hit 7 right")
    group.add_argument("-d","--draws",type=int,default=1000000,
        help="Stop after number of draws")
    parser.add_argument("-n","--numbers", nargs=7, type = int,choices=range(1, 40),
        help="Lottery numbers, if not given will be randomly selected")

    args = parser.parse_args()



    if args.numbers ==None:
        print('You did not give lottery numbers so following numbers are randomly selected')
        picked_numbers = set(random.sample(LOTTERY_NUMBERS, 7))

        print(*picked_numbers)
        print('Number of lottery draws is {:,}'.format(args.draws))
    else:
        picked_numbers = set(args.numbers)
        print('Number of lottery draws is {:,}'.format(args.draws))

    for i in range(args.draws):
        lotto_numbers = set(random.sample(LOTTERY_NUMBERS, 7))
        remaining_nbrs = set(LOTTERY_NUMBERS).difference(lotto_numbers)
        extra_nmbs = set(random.sample(remaining_nbrs, 3))


        correct_numbers = lotto_numbers&picked_numbers
        correct_extranmbs = extra_nmbs&picked_numbers

        if len(correct_numbers) > 3 and not (len(correct_numbers) == 6 and correct_extranmbs):
            index = len(correct_numbers) - 4
            WIN_LIST[index] = WIN_LIST[index] + 1
            if len(correct_numbers) == 7 and args.seven:
                print("You hit JACKPOT {} round".format(i))
                break                
        elif len(correct_numbers) == 6 and correct_extranmbs:
            six_plus_one=six_plus_one+1



    print('4 correct %i times, one out of %g\n'
          '5 correct %i times, one out of %g\n'
          '6 correct %i times, one out of %g\n'
          '6+1 correct %i times, one out of %f\n'
          '7 correct %i times, one out of %f\n'
          %(WIN_LIST[0],oneoutof(WIN_LIST[0], args.draws),
            WIN_LIST[1],oneoutof(WIN_LIST[1], args.draws),
            WIN_LIST[2],oneoutof(WIN_LIST[2], args.draws),
            six_plus_one,float(args.draws)/float(six_plus_one) if six_plus_one else 0,
            WIN_LIST[3],oneoutof(WIN_LIST[3], args.draws)))
```

Comment: can you show us yourself try ?

Comment: @d-coder I rolled back your edit as it made the OPs indentation incorrect... please be very careful when amending code blocks (it's very rare you should need to) as you completely altered the meaning of the OPs code.

Comment: @JonClements Oh! Sorry. That was not my intention at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need an import at the top of the file:

```
from itertools import count, islice
```

Then we can edit some of your code...

Firstly, set the default value of `args.draws` to be `None` - we can use this as "no limit".

```
group.add_argument("-d","--draws", type=int, default=None, help="Stop after number of draws")
```

Then, we adjust your `print` to take into account that `None` can't be formatted as a integer so we replace it with the largest possible number `float('inf')` which will successfully still display as `inf` when printed with the `{:,}` formatting, so:

```
print('Number of lottery draws is {:,}'.format(args.draws or float('inf')))
```

Then, instead of looping over a range, we loop over an infinite sequence, but cap it to `n` many elements, which is either an integer or is `None` (which means don't apply a limit to that sequence):

```
for i in islice(count(1), args.draws):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop instead.

```
 if(args.draws.length!=0)

      for i in range(args.draws):
      perform lottery draws here

 else

     while(!jackpotHit)
        perform lottery draws here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

draws = range(args.draw) if args.draw is not None else count()
for i in draws:
    perform lottery draws here
```